Static method reference in an anonymous class
Consider the following contrived "hello, world":
abstract public class Main implements java.util.function.Supplier<Runnable> {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main() {
            private void hello() {
                System.out.println("hello, world");
            }
            @Override
            public Runnable get() {
                return this::hello;
            }
        }.get().run();
    }
}

This works. Now, imagine I realize that the hello method can be made static, how do I now get the reference to that method? Static method reference require to use the name of the class, which by definition is not there. I tried just trying to refer to hello or ::hello or null::hello but these are not acceptable for the compiler.
Since the method is static, this can of course be easily worked around by putting the static method in the Main class and referring to it as Main::hello, but in a more complex setup the advantage of being able to refer to the static method would be restricting the static method to the smallest possible context. A case can be made of course that probably at that point you are probably abusing the ability to have anonymous classes, but my question mostly comes from curiosity to understand whether referring to static methods of anonymous classes is possible at all.

You could replace return this::hello; with return () -> System.out.println("hello, world"); That’s technically the same as having a private static method containing System.out.println("hello, world"); and returning a method reference to it, except that the method won’t have the name hello.

While method references are probably not really possible, another workaround might be to define a lambda and call the static function in it.
abstract public class Main implements java.util.function.Supplier<Runnable> {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main() {
            private static void hello() {
                System.out.println("hello, world");
            }
            @Override
            public Runnable get() {
                return () -> hello();
            }
        }.get().run();
    }
}

While I'm not sure whether the compiler can realize that the additional indirection is not necessary, I don't think this would be impossible.

The example above compiles with JDK 21. Maybe it wasn't possible in the past?

@MarcePuente It's already possible.

@AndreySmelik, thanks for the correction, I was really unaware of the change..

Another workaround is to name your class. You can declare your class locally, inside your main method, so you're not polluting your wider namespace. The only drawback is just one extra line of code:
public static void main(String[] args) {
    class NewMain extends Main {
        private static void hello() {
            System.out.println("hello, world");
        }
        @Override
        public Runnable get() {
            return NewMain::hello;
        }
    }
    new NewMain().get().run();
}


@MarcePuente that limitation has been dropped a few Java versions ago.

@Rob Spoor, thanks for the correction, I was really unaware of the change.
